Equivalent of describe-key for prefix keys?
describe-key works for complete keys. How can I instead describe a prefix key?
For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:
M-x describe-prefix-key C-x
And have it describe the keymap which C-x is bound to.

I found the answer which I will post here in case it is useful for someone else. The solution is to evaluate describe-key with the prefix key as an argument, rather than calling it interactively:
M-: (describe-key "\C-x") RET

Just in case you didn't know, you can type <prefix> C-h to find out which keys are bound under <prefix>.

@phils Thanks. Yes, I did know that. There is also which-key which does the same (among other things). However it doesn't reveal the keymap name.

If it's purely the binding you want to see, then you can use (key-binding KEY) or, for a specific keymap, (lookup-key KEYMAP KEY).
